# What's the best technique for this complex supervised continious regression task

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I'm facing a problem, that I don't know how to parametize, so I'm thinking some sort of neural net solution might be the best - but I am not too familiar with regression techniques within this field, so any guidance or pointers would be much appreciated.

**The problem**

A large number of workers (w1,w2,w3...wN) solves a large number of tasks (t1,t2,t3,...tN). Each task consists of doing a number of individual procedures (p1,p2,p3...pN) sequentially. Any procedure can be a part multiple tasks. Let's say that t1 = (p1,p3,p5) and t2 = (p1,p2).

I have a large very sparse dataset where a record is: w1 did t1 that is defined as (p1,p3,p5) in 32 minutes. No worker has done all tasks, or even all jobs, but all jobs has observations.

I would like to predict the time it takes a worker to a (possibly previously undone) task.

*edit:*

I'm not sure this was made clear in the problem statement, but each worker has a different level of skill, such that w1 does t1 faster than w2, but w2 does t2 faster than w1. The entire problem is centered around trying to predict the time it takes w3 to do t2, only knowing the time it took for him to do t1, utilizing the knowledge we have about the t1 times of w1 and w2.

**Further...**

The tasks are non-linear in time, such that it takes longer time to do (p1,p1) than 2*(p1).

A task can be loaded, such that p1(10) is essentially the same task as p1(20), but is more difficult. If a worker is good at p1(10), he's probably good at p1(20), but it's still a non-linear relationship in time. p(10)*2 != p(20)

---

I realize this is a complex problem, that takes some time to find a good solution for, but any hints, pointers, articles or other projects would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you're trying a heuristic approach, then regression will be helpful, but I don't see where ML and NNs come into this at all.  This is a non-linear optimization problem.  Maybe there's some paradigm I've missed here?

Comment: Heuristic or not, the purpose is to make the best possible model to solve these kind of problems.

It is a non-linear optimization problem - but it's unspecified, and i can't see any obvious way of parameterizing the problem, so im unsure of how to attack the problem.

Comment: Two suggestions to help this: (1) post on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/); this is a higher level of analysis than SO *usually* handles, and (2) Collect your various timing cases, giving a *specific* example -- with sample time -- for each case.  This will help people focus on the complexities of this problem.

Comment: Thank you @Prune - I will update the problem statement, and post the very basic solution i came up with so far. I will post the link here